What hotkey is starting a screen recording and can I turn it off?
Every once and a while when I press Win+Shift+S to take a screenshot I will miss press keys and hit some specific other key combination. When this happens a yellow border will appear around all of my monitors (my understanding is that this means something is recording my screen). No matter what I do I can't get it to go away, but a few minutes later it will disappear on it's own. While the border is present I don't see any likely culprits in task manager and after it disappears I can't find any video files saved anywhere.
Does anyone know what combination of keys I am pressing that might trigger a screen recording and how I can disable this hotkey.

It's probably the recording feature of the "Game Bar", which in general is accessed via WinG.
It has two shortcuts for recording in its "Settings" window – by default set to WinAltR to start/stop recording in general, or WinAltG to "record last 30 seconds" ('dashcam' mode that can be enabled per-app).
(I tried to add a screenshot of the "Settings" button, but I got "Image is too small: please upload an image that is at least 160x160px" so just imagine a screenshot of a 'gear' button/icon with a red freehand circle drawn around it.)


BTW, if you don't use Xbox games, it is possible to disable all its features, such as Win+G recording. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-and-remove-game-bar-windows-10-creators-update . On this PC, I've also disabled all Xbox services (one required a Registry edit).

@DrMoishePippik I already have the games bar disabled.
